# Enabling/Disabling AWS Load Balancer Target Nodes for Maintenance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have an AWS Network Load Balancer set up with several targets registered to its target group, but it seems that there is no option to enable/disable those targets for maintenance, unlike every other load balancer I've ever worked on.  Is this true, or am I missing something?  I know I can add/remove nodes from the target group but they take a long time to register/drain and I don't want to have to rebuild my target group every time I do maintenance on the nodes.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing any manual maintenance on the nodes. The proper way to do that is to have your nodes in ASG, and then you replace all instances in the ASG.

Comment: @Marcin - agreed, that would be the way to go for regular servers serving HTTPS type applications, but these are LDAP servers (hence the Network Load Balancer), each of which contain a copy of the whole DIT, consisting of 1.8 million accounts.  Loading the data can take a few hours, so isn’t so amenable to ASG processes.